# Matrix Fields Not Parsing

Tags: matrix

I have recently upgraded EE to 2.5.3, and Pixel and Tonic’s Matrix to 2.5.1 and now my Matrix fields have stopped parsing. The raw tags with curly braces are being output.

I’ve been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong.

I have tried contacting Pixel And Tonic on all the support channels I know of, and while it hasn't been that long, I *really* need to get this fixed pronto. Anyone know what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which EE version did you upgrade from? Can you post a code snippet that isn't parsing?

Comment: Upgraded from 2.5.2 to 2.5.3. Did what I thought was due diligence to check all my add-ons for compatibility. Upgraded Matrix to latest version. Admittedly did do a stupid and failed to check that it was working on the front end before updating EE itself. Wish I knew which thing caused the failure.

Here’s a code sample:

`<ul>{podcast_show_links}
<li><a target="_blank" href="{link_url}">{link_title}</a></li>{/podcast_show_links}
</ul>`

I should note that while this is one sample, this is happening to all Matrix fields from different various channels and places on the site.

Comment: Double check that extensions are enabled.

Comment: They are indeed enabled.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, the issue was a conflict with Matrix and the Multiple Relationship extension where Multiple Relationship extension was being run after Matrix and was overwriting data produced by Matrix. Apparently some change in EE 2.5.3 caused this conflict because it didn’t exist before.

I actually switched to Playa anyway since I couldn’t quite do what I wanted with Multiple Relationships so I’m going to just de-install that add-on. But if you need to run them together with EE 2.5.3, the fix is to run the following query:

```
UPDATE exp_extensions SET priority = 9 WHERE class = 'Mrelshp_ext' AND method = 'channel_entries_tagdata'
```

I hope this helps anyone else pulling their hair out over this one.

Comment: Was just heading this way to update the thread.  Thank you TJ!

Answer (score 3):

I've responded to your support email.  Happy to help here or there - let me know.

It would help to see your template, as well as to ensure that you visited the Matrix fieldtype settings in Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Matrix.

Thank you!

-Lisa Wess
Pixel & Tonic

Comment: Thank you TJ!  We can update here once we figure it out. :)

Comment: Guys, did this get resolved? If yes, can you post the fix back as an answer and accept your answer.

Comment: Bing bong! Reminding about posting the fix here.

Comment: TJ did post the answer here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1665/563 - I think only he can mark it as the actual answer? I don't see a checkmark to click. :)

Answer (score 2):

Super basic, but did you remember to update all themes folders/etc? I have done this with sad results. Also I believe @onebrightlight had posted a Matrix/EE 2.5.3 prob recently - did you see if this is related?

Comment: My comment wasn't related to this one, Jessica. :-/

Comment: I searched and did not find a related problem. I am re-uploading all the files now just to be certain. One interesting thing though, I purchased Matrix through Devotee and noticed the zip file download is named: temp_file_Matrix2.5.11.zip. I wonder if the wrong file got uploaded to devotee or something. I’ve never contacted Pixel and Tonic support before, never needed to. I hope they respond quickly.

Comment: Re-uploaded all files, visited Matrix addon page on control panel. Saw license key, clicked submit. Nothing. No change.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the source code for what is output for those un-parsed curly-braced tags, TJ. If you find that your source code shows that they're being output as HTML entities, i.e., `&#123;` and `&#124;`, it *may* be a bug in EE 2.5.3.

(I had a similar hair-pulling experience when trying to use Matrix's image replacement trick after upgrading to 2.5.3, where images uploaded to matrix were referenced as {image_1} {image_2} inside the body of a custom field. If this is an issue straight from matrix to template, this may not be helpful for you, tho.)

In the ellislab.com forum, here's a [description + link to the bug](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/224272/#1030565) (the forum post is viewable by all no matter if you're logged into ellislab.com or not.); to view the full fix, you will need to first log in to Ellislab.com before clicking that link in order to see the post re: temporary bug fix (scroll down).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately that does not seem to be the case here. I looked at the HTML source code and the curly braces were not being encoded. Just to be absolutely certain, I deleted the line(s) mentioned in the bug thread from the EE_Typography.php file. No effect. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: It was a kind of long shot. Wishing you luck!